# How do Mormons view events like the Holocaust considering that they view Adam's fall as a move forward?

Tags: lds, genesis, fall-of-man

In Christianity in general, a common view of Adam's transgression has been that it was something bad that resulted not just in a loss of something good.

Among the consequences of Adam's transgression is also the current state of affairs among mankind with death, diseases, war and so on. Out of this short list of consequences warfare is the one that has changed most toward worse during the last two centuries.

Mormons however believe that Adam's sin was a necessary step forward.

For example the answer to [this other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30144/in-mormonism-how-is-the-doctrine-of-adam-eve-inability-to-have-children-prior) says that

> Life is an opportunity to learn to choose good over evil. This could
>   not happen if there was not good or evil. (See 2 Nephi 2.)
>
> The sacrifice of the Son of God was planned from "the foundation of
>   the world" (Revelation 13:8). So also was the Fall -- which
>   necessitated the sacrifice -- known from the beginning. Mormons often
>   describe the Fall as a fall downward, but also forward.

In this question I am just focusing on the negative developments after Adam's transgression.

Presumably things like the Holocaust would never had happened if the transgression would not have happened.

However Mormons view the transgression as a necessary part of God's plan without which humankind would not have been able to learn what they needed to learn.

Because of this do they also consider the subsequent events as somehow necessary on the larger scale of things?

Comment: Mormons don't view Adam's transgression as a _sin_ -- the scriptures don't call it such. So the premise of your question is false, and the question about "all badness" doesn't follow. And another thing: you simply cannot compare the Holocaust to The Fall. I think any Mormon would be revolted to have to draw such a comparison, especially in light of a question that has a false premise.

Comment: @Matt How do Mormons view Romans 5:12, 14? Those scriptures say sin caused death, and that Adam's transgression was a sin.

Comment: @Matt, I was not comparing the Holocaust to Adam's fall in any case but it was mentioned as a consequence from it. But I have now updated the question.

Comment: “Let no man say when he is tempted, ‘I am tempted of God’: For God cannot be tempted with evil, neither tempteth He any man: But every man is tempted when he is drawn away of his own lust, and enticed (James 1:13-15.)” It has always been an absurd philosophical argument, that God predetermined evil.

Comment: @4castle see this answer (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/54496/22319) about LDS view on death

Comment: The quote you take from the answer to the other questions states that the Fall was a *fall* forward, not a step forward as you've stated.  I believe there is an important distinction there, especially in light of this question.

Comment: @depperm, 4castle's question was about [Romans 5:12,14](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rom/5.12,14?lang=eng) which he says refers to Adam's act as "sin" (not "transgression"). How does the answer you linked to address that at all?

Comment: @4castle The KJV does not say that Adam's transgression was sin: https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rom/5.12-14?lang=eng#p11 -- "the similitude of Adam’s transgression"

Comment: @Matt Right, if it's a sin to do anything even similar to Adam's transgression, then it would follow that Adam's transgression was also a sin. Genesis 2:17 says that the penalty for Adam's disobedience was death, so clearly it's the sin that Romans 5:12 is referring to which caused sin to enter into the world, "and death by sin." See also Romans 5:16.

Comment: @4castle Well, you can say that, but that's not really how the Mormons view it. Especially not as an accounting for all the sin that follows (including the Holocaust). But maybe we're just arguing semantics now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd recommend you read the [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30146/22319) to the question the OP mentions to understand LDS belief on Adam and Eve or this Ensign [article](https://www.lds.org/bc/content/ldsorg/children/resources/topics/adam-and-eve/The-Fall-of-Adam-and-Eve-2006-06-ensign.pdf).

In answer to your question, yes and no the LDS believe `subsequent events as somehow necessary on the larger scale of things.`

---

The reason why evil people can do evil things is because of [agency](https://www.lds.org/topics/agency?lang=eng):

> **[which] is the ability and privilege God gives us to choose and to act for ourselves**. Agency is essential in the plan of salvation. Without agency, we would not be able to learn or progress or follow the Savior. With it, we are “free to choose liberty and eternal life, through the great Mediator of all men, or to choose captivity and death, according to the captivity and power of the devil” ( 2 Nephi 2:27).
>
> ...
>
> The Lord has said that all people are responsible for their own motives, attitudes, desires, and actions. **Even though we are free to choose our course of action, we are not free to choose the consequences of our actions.** The consequences, whether good or bad, follow as a natural result of any choice we make.

<sub>(this doesn't mean the LDS condone atrocities)</sub>

People can also choose instead to serve others, follow God's commandments, etc.

Man purpose isn't to experience pain or to do evil. From [2 Nephi 2:25](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/2.25?lang=eng#p24) we know that:

> 25 Adam fell that men might be; and **men are, that they might have joy**.

Later in [2 Nephi 9:25,35](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/9.25,35?lang=eng#p24) it says:

> 25 Wherefore, **he has given a law; and where there is no law given there is no punishment; and where there is no punishment there is no condemnation;** and where there is no condemnation the mercies of the Holy One of Israel have claim upon them, because of the atonement; for they are delivered by the power of him.
>
> 35 Wo unto the murderer who deliberately killeth, for he shall die.

Overall [2 Nephi 2:13](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/2.13#p12) summarizes that yes bad things happen but we know they are bad because of the law. We know sadness because of happiness, if we only had good things happen all the time we wouldn't be happy because we wouldn't have known sadness.

> 13 And if ye shall say there is no law, ye shall also say there is no sin. If ye shall say there is no sin, ye shall also say there is no righteousness. **And if there be no righteousness there be no happiness.** And if there be no righteousness nor happiness there be no punishment nor misery. And if these things are not there is no God. And if there is no God we are not, neither the earth; for there could have been no creation of things, neither to act nor to be acted upon; wherefore, all things must have vanished away.

<sub>See also [The Purpose of Earth Life](https://www.lds.org/manual/doctrines-of-the-gospel-student-manual/10-purpose-of-earth-life?lang=eng)</sub>

<sub>Read [2 Nephi 2](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/2) to get a better answer about the Fall, agency, and overall a better answer then what I attempted here</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Depperm's answer, with the article/answer and Book of Mormon chapter linked therein, is much more complete than mine.  However, I wish to address one part of the OP's question:

> Presumably things like the Holocaust would never had happened if the transgression would not have happened.

First, let's reference [2 Nephi 2:22-23](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/2.22,23?lang=eng#21):

> 22 And now, behold, if Adam had not transgressed he would not have fallen, but he would have remained in the garden of Eden. And all things which were created must have remained in the same state in which they were after they were created; and they must have remained forever, and had no end.
>
> 23 And they would have had no children; wherefore they would have remained in a state of innocence, having no joy, for they knew no misery; doing no good, for they knew no sin.

Thus, in the Mormon theology, if Adam and Eve had not fallen they would have never had children.  So yes, if they had not transgressed the Holocaust would not have happened, but also everything else that has happened since they transgressed would not have happened.  Nobody would have been born to the earth, and Adam and Eve would have remained childless forever (or, until they chose to partake of the forbidden fruit).

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything., 2 Nephi 2:22-23, which is quoted in my answer.